# Operation between two 2D numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I am trying to operate on two 2D numpy arrays, such that my first numpy array's each row operate on all of the rows of second numpy array.

Array1

```
test[] = [[0.54131721 0.52305685 0.42921551, 0.37434461 0.52591475 0.36184407]
 [0.53091097 0.3000469  0.39346106, 0.29261769 0.3806552  0.33904193]
 [0.29331853 0.44518117 0.41390863, 0.2510257  0.50481932 0.43607184]]
```

Array2

```
train[] =[[0.5301304,  0.62645837, 0.44524917, 0.40806674 0.46013734 0.61033772]
 [0.43333892 0.46062429 0.56937923, 0.6451305  0.33103777 0.35859095]
 [0.60879428 0.72451976 0.2661216, 0.38850336 0.41685737 0.57226228]]
```

This is how I am saving both array:

```
import numpy as np
trainingData = np.genfromtxt('trainingData.csv', delimiter=',')
inTraining = trainingData[:, :-1]
print(inTraining)
testData = np.genfromtxt('testData.csv', delimiter=',')
inTest = testData[:, :-1]
print(inTest)
```

This is what I tried, which seems to be not even close:

```
def euclideanDistance( c1, c2):
        d1 = inTraining[]
        d2 = inTest[]
        a = math.sqrt( (d1[0]-d2[0])**2 + (d1[1]-d2[1])**2 )
        print(a)
        return a
```

Expected output should be like first list containing result of operation between:

```
[0.54131721 0.52305685 0.42921551, 0.37434461 0.52591475 0.36184407] and [[0.5301304,  0.62645837, 0.44524917, 0.40806674 0.46013734 0.61033772]
 [0.43333892 0.46062429 0.56937923, 0.6451305  0.33103777 0.35859095]
 [0.60879428 0.72451976 0.2661216, 0.38850336 0.41685737 0.57226228]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to compute distance between each row of `test` to each rows of `train`. That's `distance_matrix`:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
distance_matrix(test,train)
```

Output:

```
array([[0.27979822, 0.38277359, 0.35792442],
       [0.44997152, 0.43972939, 0.51706358],
       [0.3833412 , 0.48532177, 0.49455157]])
```

If you want numpy only code, you can look at the code of `distance_matrix` to see what's happening. Basically, it's a broadcasting action:

```
def dist_mat(x,y):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((x- y[:,None])**2, axis=-1))

dist_mat(train,test)
```

Output:

```
array([[0.27979822, 0.38277359, 0.35792442],
       [0.44997152, 0.43972939, 0.51706358],
       [0.3833412 , 0.48532177, 0.49455157]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually I am trying to implement KNN from scratch. So it has to be numpy or basic python.